# How to add an Internet RADIO STATION to RhythmBox running with a .php extension?

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

There's a *Internet Radio Station* called **Sun FM** in Sri Lanka. Among those radio stations running in Sri Lanka, **Sun FM** is one of my best radio stations I really like to listen everyday.

I'm listening it by online. *But the problem came when I'm trying to listen it via RhythemBox Player. when I'm going to run that, error comes and says* **"Couldn't start playback, This appears to be a text file."**

**Here is the URL of Sun FM Online Radio** - http://www.sunfm.lk/fb_frame.php

**And this is the URL of Sun FM web site** - http://www.sunfm.lk/

Guys.., how can I add this station in the correct way and listen? What do I want to do to configure this problem?

Comment: You realize the .php is the filetype, and the stream is likely embedded inside a player, which is subsequently embedded within that .php file?  You'd have to see if that radio station actually has *links* to their feeds that are actually feeds, not the PHP page that holds a player for said feed.

Comment: @Lord of Time - If there isn't a link for a radio station, then that means we can't listen it from the RhythemBox Radio. isn't it? Or are there any way to generate a link for that kind of stations?

Comment: They have to provide the stream.  If they only provide it via an online player, that suggests they either don't want to, can't, or don't know how to provide a dedicated stream that you can listen to externally.  In some cases you can *guess* the stream, but that's usually with really old stream players, not recent ones.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I know this is an old issue, but I fugured out how to "guess" any stream possible...

On your radio station´s webpage, using chrome, right click the player, select inspect. 
somewhere there shall be a flag named http://xxxxxxxxxxx.xx:1183274>

For example, I wanted to listen to Radio Horizonte (A Chilean station, very nice btw)
But Adding it to Rhytmbox was a pain in the ass, until I thought of that.

this is their streaming link 
http://nowplaying.mediastre.am/station/5124f1b4ed596bde7d000017

and this is what you´re looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work out

http://janthoniz.blogspot.com/2013/10/rhythmbox-radio-channel-streams.html

Happy to see someone who uses ubuntu in sri Lanka

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.