# How to add radio stations to Rythmbox

Tags: internet-radio

I'm trying to ad the iHeart station "WLS AM 890" (Link: http://www.iheart.com/live/wls-890-am-5366/) to Rythmbox, but am repeatedly met with a "Not Found" error message. I can't figure out the proper URL code to use.

Can anyone help me? (The same problem exists in both Radiotray and Banshee media player)

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/482405/15811

Comment: Basically: Use the URL at the bottom when you select a station. So dont use the website adress. Use the /kfi-177/ for the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this URL as radio station to Rhythmbox:

http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/pls/WLSAMAAC.pls

I found that URL by examining the source code of the website you linked, unfortunately there's no easier way unless your radio station provides a stream URL in an appropriate format like e.g. `pls` or `mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find quite a few radio channels to add to Rhythmbox using the advice above and this is how I do it, but it is based on UK radio and using Firefox:
Go to the radio station in question, such as classicfm
Click on the "Listen" button (in this case top right). This brings up a new window (and usually an advert you have to endure). Then right click somewhere in blank space and select "View Page Info". Switch to the "Media" tab and look for the Address with the Audio Type, right click and Copy. In this case it's http://media-the.musicradio.com/ClassicFM

Go into Rhythmbox, click Radio and then Add.
The link should be automatically pasted in from the clipboard and click Add.
The station will now be in the list, but displayed as the weblink.
Double click on the link and it will automatically assign the station name and you're done!

**Update**
By using radiomap.eu and navigating to your location and city, I've found it *a lot* easier to strip out the Audio link.